# How to show last command with expanding function in bash

Tags: bash, command-history, function

I'm using function like this.

```
$ find-grep () { find . -type f -name "$1" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "$2" ; }
```

After I type:

```
$ find-grep *.c foo
```

I want to get expanded last command string. In this case:

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "foo"
```

Is there way to do it easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A saner version of @slm's:

```
find-grep() {
  cmd=(find . -type f -name "$1" -exec grep "$2" {})
  printf '%q ' "${cmd[@]}"
  printf '+\n'
  "${cmd[@]}" +
}
```

(no need for pipes or `xargs` here) Or:

```
find-grep () (
  set -x
  find . -type f -name "$1" -exec grep "$2" {} +
)
```

(note the `()` instead of `{}` to start a subshell to limit the scope of `set -x`. Note that it does not cause more processes to be forked it's just that the `fork` for the process that will execute `find` is done earlier).

Remember you need to quote wildcard characters so they are not expanded by the shell:

```
find-grep '*.c' pattern
```

If instead, you want it to be pushed to the history, so that you see the expanded command when you press the <kbd>Up</kbd> key, you could write it:

```
find-grep() {
  cmd=$(printf '%q ' find . -type f -name "$1" -exec grep "$2" {})+
  history -s "$cmd"
  eval "$cmd"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the more correct version. What's the advantage of the cmd=(...) vs. cmd=$"..." other than it's more readable? Also why can't the `+` be included to the array assignment?

Comment: @slm, `$"..."` is for localisation, it doesn't make sense in this context. You need arrays to keep track of what the arguments are or use quoting. The `+` is not included to avoid the trailing space.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$ find-grep () {
  cmd=(find . -type f -name \"$1\" -print0 \| xargs -0 grep \"$2\")
  printf "%s\n" "${cmd[*]}" 
  eval "${cmd[*]}"
}
```

#### Example

Here's some sample data.

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 4 Sep 21 10:44 1.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 4 Sep 21 10:44 2.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Sep 21 10:22 3.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Sep 21 10:22 4.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Sep 21 10:22 5.c
```

Here's our function in action, 2 of the files contain the string "foo".

```
$ find-grep '*.c' "foo"
find . -type f -name "*.c" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "foo"
./2.c:foo
./1.c:foo
```

#### Explanation

This particular version of your function does the following things differently.

1. We define a variable with your command, `$cmd=(find....)`. The command is wrapped into an array, `(..)`.
2. We echo the constructed array `$cmd` using `printf`. We pass the elements of the array using the `*` notation, `${cmd[*]}`, so that we get the array as a single string, rather than as a discrete list of elements.
3. Finally we evaluate the array `$cmd`, which runs it.

#### Another approach

You could also wrap the function like this: `set -x ...function... set +x`, which has the effect of turning on the debugging just for the duration of the `...function...`, and then turning it off.

```
$ find-grep () { 
  set -x
  find . -type f -name "$1" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "$2"
  set +x
}
```

#### Example

```
$ find-grep *.c foo
+ find . -type f -name '*.c' -print0
+ xargs -0 grep foo
+ set +x
```

This approach isn't as easy to read but it's showing you the same gross functions, just broken up based on how they were executed. First the `find ...`, followed by the `xargs ...`.

Comment: Thanks slm! I'd use this way. Is it ok if I understand there is no easy way to expand string `find-grep *.c foo` to original command, if the function is not defined like this?

Comment: @Tetsu - I provided an alternative method. I can't think of another way to do this.

Comment: That won't work properly if arguments contain a few shell special characters which will be typically the case as it's meant to take patterns (which by the way the OP forgot to quote (`*.c`)) and regexps.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - tried to address some of your points, if you get a second please take a look and let me know if it does so, thanks!

Comment: You don't need an array if you're passing a _command line_ to `eval`. However, you need need to escape all the special characters in $1 and $2 (and you need to quote your variables as always). Putting double quotes around them wont's work. If `$1` is `'*"*'` for instance or $2 is `'`'`, that won't be enough. Hence the `printf %q` in the solution I gave.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I was afraid you were going to say those things...I used the arrays since they were easier to read, IMO. Thanks for the feedback!